# Running a Live USB with multiple partitions

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub

I have a USB stick that I use for general computer repair. I've got Clonezilla, GParted, the Debian installer and the WIndows installer.

These are the zip versions, and each live on 4 different partitions. When I go into my UEFI to boot, I can select one of these partitions and it takes me correctly to the respective version of grub.

However, when I then try to load an image, it always loads the one in the first partition.

After investigating I realised that `search --set -f /live/vmlinuz` was the culprit, since it was always finding the first partition and setting the root to that. I figured this was an easy fix and changed the entry to `search --set -u`  with the partition ID for the respective partition, but this also didn't seem to work. It still booted the first partition every time.

I have two ideas of how to solve this, but I need some advice in how to do it.

The first idea is to have the first partition of the USB drive be a dedicated grub install with entries to load each respective partition. However, I have a feeling this will suffer from the same issue as I'm having editing each respective grub install.

The second idea is to somehow have grub specifically load the install on the partition it was booted from, rather than trying to find the partition that contains the loader. Is this possible?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Instead of trying to confusingly describe what you have now, perhaps you need to at least show what the current grub menu looks like,

Comment: "*since it was always finding the first partition and setting the root to that*" -- You might confusing the steps that occur during boot. Don't know about the Windows Installer, but Linux is normally told (via the kernel command line) where to find the rootfs & what kind of fs it is. If the image is built for installing in the first partition, but you move the image to another partition, then the command line is wrong. Or if Linux is going to use an initramfs, then the cpio archive is either already part of the kernel image, or a separate archive file needs to loaded with the kernel image.

Comment: Each partition has its own grub which is preconfigured for the release. Its just the thing I downloaded from the GParted and Clonezilla release pages. Any grub instance from any partition will always load the portable os in the first partition, due to grub.cfg using `search --set -f /live/vmlinuz`. This sets grub root to the first partition every time, since it returns that partition in its search.

Comment: Ventoy does what you want and boot ISOs directly. You're making a lot more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: At this point a big part of me wants to know why what I'm doing isn't working, and how to fix it as it is. Out of curiosity as much as anything. The downside to booting ISOs as well is it means everything is lost on next boot, whereas the USB filesystem versions are more persistent.

Comment: https://www.ventoy.net/en/plugin_persistence.html There! Certainly "persistence" isn't applicable to Windows installers, it only applies to some live Linux distros. You're trying to reinvent the wheel by making it square then trying to understand why it doesn't work as good as the round one and then trying to file down the corners to make it round-ish again.

Comment: Oh yeah that's fine, it was mostly the linux live installers I cared about anyway. I'm still curious about what I was attempting from an academic standpoint, but this definitely looks great in terms of functionality and usability. ty!